# Symfony2 passing array to FormBuilder

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony

I would like to create a form which has multiple input fields corresponding to the elements of an array. In ASP.Net MVC 3 I had the ModelBuilder that encoded information about the underlying model inside the input HTML tags and rebuilt the model automatically on POST but I haven't managed to find something similar in Symfony2.
Could anyone tell me whether in Symfony2 there is a way of telling the FormBuilder that the field it receives by calling the add method is actually an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the form '[Collection](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/collection.html)' field type. See the [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/index.html) entry on '[How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)'